# passing an async response "through" a thunk

Tags: redux-thunk

Is it possible to pass an async "response" through a thunk? Given the action creator below:

```
export function emitLoadPlot(json_req) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios.post(URI, {
      json_req
    })
    // .then(() => dispatch(
    //   emitTxRxAlert("yellow", "Received plot from server")
    // ))
    .then((response) => dispatch({
      type: EMIT_PLOT_DATA_REQ,
      payload: response
    }))
    .then(() => dispatch(
      emitTxRxAlert("green", "Loaded plot model")
    ))
    .then(() => dispatch({
      type: EMIT_LOAD_PLOT
    }))
    .then(() => dispatch({
      type: EMIT_VIEW_STATUS
    }))
  };
}
```

If I uncomment the Alert dispatch the `response` never makes it to where it's needed. Makes sense. Some of these calls (and the manipulation on the client end) take a long time to complete and I'd like to interleave client UI alerts (say) between when the async request returns in the browser and when it loads into the redux store. On this slow laptop the network request takes a lot less time than processing the `response`.

Is there any way for me to pass the `response` (or the reference to the `response`) through the first thunk above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `then()` returns a promise of the result of your callback.

Your callback returns whatever `dispatch()` returns, which is not the value you want.

Instead, you need to return the original value:

```
.then(response => {
  dispatch(...);
  return response;
})
```

Comment: I both love and hate it when answers are so simple I have to be an idiot to miss it. Thanks.